# Как динамически создать массив TextBlockов и задать им разные значения?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Пробовал сделать так, но получаю последний файл Я и все

```
List <string> xmlfiles = new List <string> ();
List <TextBlock> lg = new List <TextBlock> ();

public void XML()
{
    FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    folderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
    folderBrowserDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
        letterList.Clear();
        xmlfiles.Clear();

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath);

        letterList = new List <string> () {
        "А.xml", "Б.xml", "В.xml", "Г.xml", "Д.xml", "Е.xml", "Ё.xml", "Ж.xml", "З.xml", "И.xml", "Й.xml", "К.xml", "Л.xml", "М.xml", "Н.xml", "О.xml", "П.xml", "Р.xml", "С.xml", "Т.xml", "У.xml", "Ф.xml", "Х.xml", "Ц.xml", "Ч.xml", "Ш.xml", "Щ.xml", "Ъ.xml", "Ы.xml", "Ь.xml", "Э.xml", "Ю.xml", "Я.xml"};

        foreach(string letter in letterList) {
            FileInfo[]rgFiles = di.GetFiles(letter);
            foreach(FileInfo fi in rgFiles) {
                xmlfiles.Add(fi.FullName);
            }
        }

        foreach(string file in xmlfiles) {
            if (File.Exists(file)) {
                try {
                    xmltez.Load(file);

                    XmlNode inXmlNode = xmltez.DocumentElement;

                    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                        XmlNode nd = inXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("//Root/Statya[position()='" + i + "']/Termin");
                        if (nd != null) {
                            lg = new List <TextBlock> ();
                            for (int j = 0; j < lg.Count; j++) {
                                lg[j].Width = 200;
                                lg[j].TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                                lg[j].TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
                                lg[j].Text = nd.InnerText + "n" + nd.NextSibling.InnerText;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(XmlException xmlEx) {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(xmlEx.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void V()
{
    if (meshClicked == mesh3D1) {
        tooltip.Content = lg;
        tooltip.IsOpen = true;
        tooltip.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    if (meshClicked == mesh3D2) {
        tooltip.Content = lg;
        tooltip.IsOpen = true;
        tooltip.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: А кол - во TextBlock'ов определённое, или динамическое?

Comment: Да вообщем есть 104 объекта. Нужно для них сделать 104 TextBlocka и у этих TextBlock вывести разный текст из XML файлов. И задать все эти 104 TextBlocka свойству Content ToolTipa.

Answer (score 2):

Тут на каждой итерации цикла создается новый список, соответственно с единственным текстблоком.

```
lg = new List <TextBlock> (); // создавать нужно 1 раз, а здесь на каждый файл
```

Вобще-то такой подход в корне неверный для WPF. WPF пропогандирует идею MVVM и DataBinding.

По правильному, нужно было создать шаблон на ксамле (в ресурсах)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" ..остальные свойства../>
</DataTemplate>
```

Потом создать ListBox, которому в ItemsSource положить(или привяззать через Binding) коллекцию строк, а в ItemTemplate указать `{StaticResource Template}`

Comment: Так мне нужно прочитать текст из всех файлов. На XAMLe я это создать не могу,  потому что у класса MeshGeometry нет ни ToolTipов, ни TextBlockoв и нужно это создать из кода.

Comment: Ну тогда извиняюсь за замечание, просто часто WPF используют просто как расширение Windows Forms и пишут код как на формах, только с красивыми градиентами.